# Angular2 Source Maps not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli, source-maps

I have a standard angular app build with the angular cli using ng new

I have the following angular version

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.2
node: 6.9.5
os: win32 x64
```

and in my ts-config file I have the following

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

However, Source maps are not available, and I have an ionic app where they work. Have i missed something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What shows under that (no domain) dropdown?

Comment: ive updated the question

Comment: in the dist folder that is created on `ng build` is there `.js.map` files?

Comment: ng serve doesn't generate a dist folder

Comment: My suggestion is to pin point it before the browser. Try an `ng build` and check the dist folder that is created. It should contain only `.js` and `.js.map` files.

Comment: dist folder within your local editor not in the browser

Comment: if you expand `webpack://`->`your app path` folder you will see `ts` files you can debug.

Comment: Yes, but it should show up under localhost, as it does with `ionic` apps.